# Finding cartesian equation of plane

Tags: vectors

Given plane $\alpha$ contains a line $L$ with vector equation $r=tj$ and point $P(3,-1,2)$.The question ask to find the Cartesian equation of $\alpha$ and i don't exactly know how to tackle this question.Given that $r=tj$ does it means the only nonzero value is for $j$ ?Step by step guide is appreciated. :)

Comment: They mean $r=t(0,1,0)$. Just see the parametric equation of a line.

Answer (score 1):

The plane $\alpha$ is generated by the two vectors J and $\vec{OP}=(3,-1,2)$, so if $M=(x,y,z)$ is a point in $\alpha$ : $$\vec{OM}=a\vec{J}+b\vec{OP}$$ for some reals a and b.
We obtain $$x=a*0+3*b$$
$$y=a*1+(-1)*b$$$$z=a*0+2*b$$ then the equation is $$2x-3z=0$$